# window.location not setting / webView shouldStartWithLoadRequest not being called

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I've been working from a couple of topics I found here on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to get it right.

My app stores a HTML page locally and I'm trying to get some Javascript to work with my obj-c code.

This is my JavaScript file:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction()
{
    window.location.href = "ios:webToNativeCall";
    alert(window.location.href);
}
</script>
```

and this is my obj-c method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"test");
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"]){
        NSLog(@"test");
        [self webToNativeCall];
        return NO;
    }
```

I would post two separate topics, but I have a feeling these issues are linked. In the JS file, the alert prints the correct path for the .html file in my system. Neither of the `NSLog(@"test")`s are being executed.

I have the WebView delegate set up :

```
@interface WebBrochureViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: Does the UIWebViewDelegate method get called when you load the page originally?

Comment: I'm pretty new to iOS so I'm not sure how to check that?

Comment: The Objective C method that you posted (`-webView:shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:`). Is it called when the page first loads? It should be called every time the page is loaded. Is the first "test" being printed into the console?

Comment: No, neither of the tests are being printed. In the Storyboard, I ctrl-dragged from the UIWebView to the Controller to the yellow circle to set up the delegate, but that didn't do anything, so I added in the `<UIWebViewDelegate>` manually

Comment: You're problem probably isn't with the UIWebView, but rather with your Storyboard. Storyboards are great for rapid development, but if you don't know the fundamentals, you should learn them first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm slowly learning as I go. I've tried reading documentation, but I find it hard to soak it in without actual trial and error. Could you point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong, or is it too hard to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an issue with your Storyboard setup. You should try a simple case first as proof of concept, and then learn how to adapt it to a bigger picture.

Here's a good simple view controller for your problem.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [view addSubview:({
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        webView.delegate = self;
        self.webView = webView;
    })];
    self.view = view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSAssert(url!=nil, @"Could not find URL for index.html");
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self.webView loadData:data
                  MIMEType:@"text/html"
          textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
                   baseURL:nil];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"[%@] Delegate method started.", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"ios"]) {
        NSLog(@"[%@] Communication Received.", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```